# Core data object not appending to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I am having a small issue with appending my Core Data object to an array. Everything is being saved correctly in Core Data, but when I checked the array, it was empty. The code looks as follows:

```
func saveQA(question: String, answer: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Card", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let newQA = Card(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    newQA.question = question
    newQA.answer = answer

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        playerCards.append(newQA)

    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

What seemed to work for me was changing my array from type Card, to type String. Then appending both newQA.question and newQA.answer separately to playerCards. Although I am unsure this is a valid solution. As I am unsure the question and answer will stay linked to each other that way. Any help is great, thank you in advance.

Comment: can you check the data base  ( download app bundle and check your table) ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did do that, i checked my sqlite file to make sure everything was saved correctly which it was. It is just not appending to the array.

Comment: i'm sorry , but are you sure your playerCards != nil  ?

Comment: I am not sure if i am misunderstaning. That is what my issue is. playerCards is my array which is staying empty after i pass in arguments for question and answer. Everything is being saved correctly to core data, but not being appended to the array.

Comment: if your array is nil and you didn't alloc and init ,  it so you cant't append data to it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add data to you NSMutableArray like this :

```
playerCards.addObject(newQA)
```